# App termination event for cleaning up resources

Tags: events, titanium, appcelerator, exit, termination

Here's the deal:

I'm building a mobile app with Appcelerator Titanium. It will be deployed to iOS and Android devices.

I use the Titanium.Database module to cache incoming data that the app displays. I would like to close() the database (and maybe perform some other actions) when the user presses the home button/dismisses the app. While in the background, an app can be killed without warning (either manually or by the system), so I would like to do some clean up in anticipation of this event.

I see the 'pause', 'resume' and 'resumed' events mentioned in the API docs, but they're iOS-only.

**So.... How do I take care of business on Android?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to current activity in Android:

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('pause', callback);
```

or

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.addEventListener('resume', callback);
```

Maybe you are asking how to do that on iOS? I would try with a window listener to 'focus' and 'blur'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know how to do it on iOS, but just not on Android. If I understand this correctly, there is no way to listen for these events "app-wide". If I have a single function that I want to run every time someone dismisses the app (using the home button) or resumes it, I need to attach this function to the events of EACH window/activity that is displayed? There is no global "pause/resume" event?

Comment: Exactly, I think there is no global pause/resume, essentially because there isn't such event even on native Android. You need to listen to each activity, that on Appcelerator means (from official docs):

`In Titanium, you can create either "lightweight" or a "heavyweight" windows, as described on the Titanium.UI.Window reference page. A heavyweight window creates a new Activity. A lightweight window runs inside the same activity as the code that created it.`